# Windows Scripting Host HTML Application - event on exit?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, wsh, hta

I've created a Windows Scripting Host HTML Application. Is there a way to fire an event when/before the user exits the program? I want to spawn an "Are you sure you want to quit?" prompt.

I got the `onbeforeunload` event to fire the following script:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

The prompt displays as it should. However the program exits regardless of whether the user clicks <kbd>OK</kbd> or <kbd>Cancel</kbd>. How do I prevent the program from closing?

Comment: [`onbeforeunload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I added

 window.onbeforeunload = really

 function really()
 {
  alert("Really?")
 }

but it didn't work.

Comment: You should not use function declaration for this. An anonymous function is what you need here: window.onbeforeunload=function () {alert('really?');};

Comment: Still didn't work. :(

Comment: Never mind! The reason it wasn't working is that I already had a script for that event written in the HTA itself (rather than the JS files I am normally working on). I have another problem with the event. I will add it to my first post.